# different formatter for the mouse position in an interactive window

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I have a plot where in abscissa I have the year 2022, and in ordinate a function of time

```
In [215]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     ...: from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
     ...: from numpy import linspace, sin
     ...: 
     ...: T0 = (2022-1970)*365.25 ; T1 = T0+365 ; T = np.linspace(T0, T1, 366)
     ...: w = 6.28/40
     ...: 
     ...: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,5), constrained_layout=1)
     ...: ax.plot(T,40+15*np.sin(w*T-0.2))
     ...: ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator(bymonth=range(13)))
     ...: ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b %Y"))
     ...: 
     ...: plt.show()
```

As you can see from the code, the function is plotted with a one day resolution, but because of my choice for the formatting of x-tick-labels when I move the mouse over the interactive window what I see in the upper right corner is just, e.g., "x=May 2022 y=43.31".

Is it possible to have a different formatter for the interactive window display of the mouse position?

Comment: @JohanC If you post the above as an answer, I'll be glad to accept it. Also, an answer is more visible than a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ax.fmt_xdata`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_xdata.html) controls the formatting of the coordinate in the status bar.
By default, it uses the same format as the x-axis, but you can assign a more specific one.

Here is an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import MonthLocator, DateFormatter
import numpy as np

T0 = (2022 - 1970) * 365.25
T1 = T0 + 365
T = np.linspace(T0, T1, 366)
w = 6.28 / 40

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 5), constrained_layout=1)
ax.plot(T, 40 + 15 * np.sin(w * T - 0.2))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MonthLocator(bymonth=range(13)))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter("%b %Y"))
ax.fmt_xdata = DateFormatter("%d %b %Y")
plt.show()
```

[image: using ax.fmt_xdata]

You could even go one step further, and override the [ax.format_coord](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_coord.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.format_coord) function. This is a function, given an x and y value, to produce the full coordinate string to be displayed in the status bar. By default, it just combines `ax.fmt_xdata` and `ax.fmt_ydata`.

Also the [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library might be of interest. With it, you can obtain the xy coordinates of the nearest point on the curve, and show that information as an annotation, or as overriding the status bar.